# Update production code without affecting the ui

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I already successfully deployed my web app on AWS . Now, whenever I have updates/new features to be deployed, I have to execute `git pull` then `npm run build` `pm2 restart app`. This takes time to build since I have many pages added. Then, the issue is, it affects the ui in the front-end like error 404, 502 while on `build`.

What should I do in order to update the production site without affecting the ui whenever I build the code?

Comment: You can't. The whole point about a deploy is its a completely new release. Even if the changes are minor. That being said if you have a good command of git version control you can always swap it back again

Comment: Are you asking how to setup a ci/cd pipeline? While your app is building it will mangle the application, that's why you build on a ci server and deploy the new containers/builds with something like Kubernetes or AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Comment: Could you provide more details about which AWS services you are using? E.g. if you connect your repo to AWS Amplify and let it do the build, then it will keep the previous version running until the build is completed. We never noticed a downtime this way,

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I deployed it on EC2 instance